# How to use Gradle task output from included build

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, build-system

So I need to copy the outputs of a couple projects in a Gradle composite project to a local directory.
Normally, in a single build, it would go like this:

```
tasks{
  register<Copy>("copyJarToLocalServer"){
    from(jar) // autowires to jar.outputs.files , the outputs of the jar task
    into("some\\dir")
  }
}
```

Now I need to do the same thing from a composite build; I used `includeBuild` to include some projects.
The problem is that I cannot find a way to grab the output from the 'jar' tasks from those included projects.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69323113/how-to-get-property-of-gradle-task-from-an-included-build) unanswered question seems to have a similar problem.

**Things I tried**

I tried getting the task from `gradle.includedBuild`:

```
register<Copy>("copyJarToLocalServer") {
  from(gradle.includedBuild("witheronia-maze").task("jar")) // witheronia-maze is one of the included builds
  into("some\\dir")
}
```

This doesn't work because includedBuild().task() returns a TaskReference, not the actual task.

I tried getting all the tasks that have that name recursively:

```
register<Copy>("copyJarToLocalServer") {
  from(getTasksByName(":jar", true).flatMap { it.outputs.files }) // Also tried "jar", ":witheronia-maze:jar" etc.
  into("some\\folder")
}
```

This gives the task output `NO-SOURCE` and doesn't do anything

I tried getting the project and then getting the task

```
from(project("witheronia-maze").getTasksByName("jar", false).flatMap { it.outputs.files })
// or
from(project("witheronia-maze").tasks.findByPath("jar"))
```

This tells me the project was not found in root project, also tried "../witheronia-maze" (actual path), ":witheronia-maze"
( I think an included build is not actually considered a project )

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that I used `includeBuild` to include the other project's build.
This does not add it as a project, and you can't access it's tasks.
I solved this by using `include` instead and setting the project path.

```
include(":witheronia-maze")
project(":witheronia-maze").projectDir = file("../witheronia-maze")
// Without setting the path manually it would put the project inside the composite, which I don't want
```

The final Copy task now looks like this:

```
register<Copy>("copyJarToLocalServer") {
    from(project(":witheronia-maze").tasks.getByPath("jar"))
    into("some\\dir")
}
```

EDIT:
The above is **not** the solution. `include` does make the tasks resolve correctly, but dependencies do not get substituted anymore and won't resolve.
I now use a task in the dependencies that copies the required artifacts to a folder in `/build`:

```
register<Copy>("pluginJar"){
    from(jar)
    into(buildDir.resolve("pluginJar"))
}
```

And then in the composite build:

```
register<Copy>("copyJarToLocalServer"){
    from(gradle.includedBuild("witheronia-maze").projectDir.resolve("build/pluginJar/"))
    to("some\\dir")
}
```

Comment: yep not much documentation. From my understanding, I believe that ```include``` would be based on your current project/repo, where use of ```includeBuild``` is based on a completely external project/repo. I may be wrong!

Comment: Welp, my answer actually does not work, it seems I need to use `includeBuild` anyways.
If I use `include` the tasks do resolve perfectly, but then it doesn't actually resolve the dependencies of the included builds. e.g. it resolves witheronia-maze but not the dependencies of that ( probably only includeBuild does dependency substitution ) ( And you can't use `include` and `includeBuild` together )